# xsl multiply using a key

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry, I don't know how to ask the question.  I have 3 xml doc.  I have an xsl that is working except for I can't figure out how the total of the price times the quantity.  I'm running out of time.  Please help...
Here is the xsl---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:variable name = "custIn" select = "document('cust.xml')" />
    <xsl:variable name = "prodIn" select = "document('prod.xml')" />
    <xsl:key name="custN" match="customer" use="@custID" />
    <xsl:key name="prodN" match="product" use="@prodID" />
    <xsl:template match="/orders">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Order List</title>
                <link href="cust.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            </head>

            <body>
                <div id="wrap">
                    <h1>
                        <img src = "logo.png" alt="My Things" /></h1>
                    <h2>Our Orders</h2>
                    <table id="orderTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order Num</th>
                            <th>Cust</th>
                            <th>Gr</th>                         
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>                            
                            <th>Total Cost</th>
                            <th>Order Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select = "order">
                            <xsl:sort select="orderDate" />
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@orderID" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:variable name="cID" select="@custID" />
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$custIn">
                                        <xsl:value-of select = "key('custN', $cID)/concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)" />
                                    </xsl:for-each></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="prodGrp"/></td>
                                <xsl:variable name="pID" select="@prodID" />
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$prodIn">
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="key('prodN', $pID)/prodName" /></td>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="key('prodN', $pID)/format-number(prodPrice, '$###,##0.00')" /></td>                               
                                    </xsl:for-each>                                 
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="prodQty"/></td>

<!-- can't calculate the total for the orders, need the price for each from the products.xml
--can bring in the price each her <xsl:value-of select="key('prodN', $pID)/format-number(prodPrice, '$###,##0.00')"
but has to be multiplied by the prodQty from the orders.xml -->                                 
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(prodQty * 5, '$###,##0.00')" />
                                </td>

                                <td><xsl:value-of select="format-date(orderDate,'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>               
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--ord.xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <order orderID = "ord10007" custID = "cust100030" prodID = "prod001" >
        <orderDate>2017-02-02</orderDate>
        <prodGrp>pencil</prodGrp>
        <prodQty>6</prodQty>
    </order>
    <order orderID = "ord10020" custID = "cust100031" prodID = "prod010" >
        <orderDate>2017-03-03</orderDate>
        <prodGrp>pen</prodGrp>
        <prodQty>4</prodQty>     
    </order>
    <order orderID = "ord10050" custID = "cust10030" prodID = "prod010" >
        <orderDate>2017-04-04</orderDate>
        <prodGrp>pen</prodGrp>
        <prodQty>7</prodQty>
    </order>
<orders>
```

---prod.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <product prodID="prod001">
        <prodGrp>pencil</prodGrp>
        <prodName>green</prodName>
        <description>write nice</description>
        <prodPrice>4.95</prodPrice>
        <date>2017-02-02</date>
        <images>
            <img src="pencil.jpg"/>
        </images>
    </product>
    <product prodID="prod010">
        <prodGrp>pen</prodGrp>
        <prodName>thick pen</prodName>
        <description>easy to grip</description>
        <prodPrice>.95</prodPrice>
        <date>2017-01-01</date>
        <images>
            <img src="pen.jpg"/>
        </images>
    </product>
</list>
```

Need 4 from order times 4.95 from product.  Thank you in advance...

Comment: Are you really using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I'm using the command prompt with java net.sf.saxon Transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, then you can use key directly on another document without having to switch the context to it first, like you're doing now.

Here's a simplified example. This is assuming `ord.xml` is the input document for the XSLT transformation.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:param name="products" select="document('prod.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="product-by-id" match="product" use="@prodID" />

<xsl:template match="/orders">
    <!-- skipped  -->  
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Order Num</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>                            
            <th>Total Cost</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="order">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@orderID" />
                </td>
                <!-- skipped  -->  
                <xsl:variable name="product" select="key('product-by-id', @prodID, $products)" />
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$product/prodName" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($product/prodPrice, '$#,##0.00')" />
                </td>  
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="prodQty" />
                </td>  
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($product/prodPrice * prodQty, '$#,##0.00')" />
                </td>  
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(orderDate,'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>               
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your input example, alongside the `prod.xml` file, you should see a result like this:

[image]

Comment: It's incredible how much dead space is in the brain when you are tire. Can someone help me figure out how to 1.  create an xsl that calculates a subtotal price and a total of all orders and then use that xsl within the one on the example her to calculate the total cost per customer (subtotal) and the total cost for all the customers in the order xml?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question and make sure to include the customers file, along with the exact expected result.