# XSL merging xml files with dfiferent roots, related by 1 attribute

Tags: ajax, xml, xslt

So I've been given two XML files, categories.xml and products.xml,
with the following format:

**Categories.xml**

```
<CategoriesRoot>
   <Categories>
      <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName></CategoryName>
        <Description></Description>
   </Categories>
   <Categories>
      <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName></CategoryName>
        <Description></Description>
   </Categories>
</CategoriesRoot>
```

and
**Products.xml**

```
<ProductsRoot>
   <Products>
      <ProductID>1</ProductID>
         <ProductName></ProductName>
         <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
         <UnitQuantity></UnitQuantity>
         <UnitPrice></UnitPrice>
   </Products>
   <Products>
      <ProductID>2</ProductID>
         <ProductName></ProductName>
         <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
         <UnitQuantity></UnitQuantity>
         <Price></Price>
   </Products>
</ProductsRoot>
```

How would you merge two XML files with different roots using XSL to get the output

**Merged.xml**

```
<CategoriesRoot>
   <Categories>
      <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName></CategoryName>
        <Description></Description>
          <Products>
            <ProductID>1</ProductID>
              <ProductName></ProductName>
              <UnitQuantity></UnitQuantity>
              <Price></Price>
          </Products>
   </Categories>
   <Categories>
      <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName></CategoryName>
        <Description></Description>
          <Products>
            <ProductID>2</ProductID>
              <ProductName></ProductName>
              <UnitQuantity></UnitQuantity>
              <Price></Price>
          </Products>
   </Categories>
</CategoriesRoot>
```

I've only come across questions about merging two related XML files, having the same root tag. Any help will be appreciated~ Thanks!

Comment: "*I've only come across questions about merging two related XML files, having the same root tag.*" Really? I found one almost immediately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838276/xsl-multiply-using-a-key/43838618#43838618

Comment: And here's another using XSLT 1.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857921/i-was-trying-to-get-sibling-of-xml-look-up-file-based-on-specfic-condition/25859743#25859743